# Writing one regular expression for string in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write one regular expression for string. Let us say there is a string RBY_YBR where _ represents empty so we can recursively replace the alphabets and _ and the result is RRBBYY_ . There can be two or more alphabet pairs can be formed or something like this also RRR . 
Conditions
1). Left or right alphabet should be the same.
2). If there is no _ then the alphabet should be like RRBBYY not RBRBYY or RBYRBY etc.
3). There can be more than one underscore _ . 
From regular expression I am trying to find whether the given string can satisfy the regular expression or not by replacing the character with _ to form a pattern of consecutive alphabets
The regular expression which I wrote is

```
String regEx = "[A-ZA-Z_]";
```

But this regular expression is failing for RBRB. since there is no empty space to replace the characters and RBRB is also not in a pattern.
How could I write the effective regular expression to solve this.

Comment: You regex looks strange. It seems to match only one character. Did you try "[A-Z_]+" ? Still this will not solve "left or right alphabet should be the same" (whatever that means)

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Means after recursive replacing of alphabet and _ in a string the final result should be like RRBBYY_ . So I am just trying to write one regex which can satisfy that yes a pattern like RRBBYY_ can be formed

Comment: "Alphabet" is what confuses me here. Do you mean "a character in the range A-Z"? Could you please provide a String only consisting of characters and underscores which shall NOT match your regex?

Comment: Oh, or do you mean that the **count** of every character used must be even?

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht yea by saying alphabet I mean a character. like RBRBRB is a string and there is no _ for replacing string with _ . So it can not form into RRRBBB. My intention here is to write one regex which can satisfy that a pattern of consecutive characters can be form or not

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht no it can be odd too

Comment: Call me stupid, but I do not get it. Let us start with matching instead of replacing. RBRBRB shall be invalid, but RBRBRB_ would be valid? RRR would be valid, and RRRBB would be invalid?

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Yes RBRBRB is invalid because there is no empty space for recursively replacing the alphabet with _ . And it's also not matching a pattern of consecutive same alphabets. RRR is valid because there is a consecutive pattern of same character RRRBB is also valid because there is consecutive pattern of same alphabet.

Comment: Or else will you please share your email id with me so that I could mail you my question breifly.

Comment: So there there are no two letters allowed with any other letter in between or there has to be an underscore? Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/dtzAQQ/1)?

Comment: @SebastianProske There can be underscore or not underscore if there is no underscore the pattern should be of consecutive same characters not like RBRBRB or RBYRBY. If there is underscore that means we can replace character and underscore to form a pattern of consecutive same characters

Comment: `RRBBBBRR` shouldn't be valid either, right? What about `ABCDEFG`, do characters need to be repeated at least once?

Comment: @SebastianProske Should be more than one

Comment: @SebastianProske RRBBBBRR is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as I understand it, a matching string shall **either** consist only of same characters being grouped together, **or** must contain at least one underscore.

So, RRRBBR would be invalid, while RRRRBB, RRRBBR_, and RRRBB_R_ would all be valid.

After comment of question creator, additional condition: Every character must occur 0 or 2 or more times.

As far as I know, this is not possible with Regular Expressions, as Regular Expressions are finite-state machines without "storage". You would have to "store" each character found in the string to check that it won't appear later again.

I would suggest a very simple method for verifying such strings:

```
public static boolean matchesMyPattern(String s) {
    boolean withUnderscore = s.contains("_");

    int[] found = new int[26];

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (ch != '_' && (ch < 'A' || ch > 'Z')) {
            return false;
        }

        if (ch != '_' && i > 0 && s.charAt(i - 1) != ch && found[ch - 'A'] > 0
                && !withUnderscore) {
            return false;
        }
        if (ch != '_') {
            found[ch - 'A']++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
        if (found[i] == 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This will fail for this test condition x_y__x even though we can move to find a pattern like xxy__ but here y is not forming a pair. Atleast a pair should be form

Comment: Hm? This will return true for x_y__x. This is not what you want? Every character must occur 0 or at least 2 times?

Comment: yea at least a pair of consecutive character should be there. May be more than 2 like RRR or RRRBBB etc.

Comment: Yea every character in a given string must be occurred at least two times

Comment: No still failed

Comment: no I have converted the string to upper case and then passing to your function.

Comment: This time it gave me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException . Please share your email id I will mail you my question

Comment: This is not Upwork, I will have to answer it here. Well, finally I fired up Eclipse to test it :-) Now it should work.

Comment: would you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038892/prevent-arrayoutofboundexception-for-three-or-more-strings-concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Please take my answer with a grain of salt, since it's a bit of a "Fastest gun in the West" post.

It follows the same assumptions as Florian Albrecht's answer. (thanks)

I believe that this will solve your problem:

```regex
(([A-Za-z])(\2|_)+)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/7TfSVc/1

It works by using the second capturing group and ensuring that more of it follow, or there are underscores.

Known bug: it does not work if an underscore starts a string.

#### EDIT

This one is better, though I forgot what I was doing by the end of it.

```regex
(([A-Za-z_])(\2|_)+|_+[A-Za-z]_*)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/7TfSVc/4

Comment: Good one but this will faild for this test case  __  .

Comment: Which case did it fail? I'd like to fix it for you, and improve my skills

Comment: It fail for RRBB and also for __

Comment: Under RRBB there is not empty space so there should be no movement but RRBB for a consecutive pair of character. so it should print successful and for __ is itself a pair

Comment: wait, so why should `RRBBYY` match, but `RRBB` shouldn't? (I might have misunderstood you here, sorry)

Comment: I just used your regex and the output prints fail.

Comment: Try the latest one (and check the example link for proof). I think it's pretty darn good =)